# XAML of UserControl cannot be located despite existing

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I created a User Control. Now I want to add this to a window.

I added to my XAML:

```
xmlns:my="clr-namespace:Namespace.Of.My.UserControl"
```

Now I want to instantiate it:

```
<my:MyUserControl/>
```

The XAML designer now complains that it cannot locate the XAML for the user control.

Strange enough, if I create another user control and add it, it works. Sometimes, when I close and re-open the solution, the user control which was not found in first place IS found and displayed, but when I delete and re-add it to the XAML, I get the same error.

I already cleaned and re-built my whole solution to no avail.

What is going wrong here?

Comment: Is your UserControl inside the same assembly as the XAML in which you are using it?

Comment: Yes, it is in the same assembly.

Comment: Try to move it into a separate assembly. I've encountered this problem a lot of times, and separating it always helped! Of-course, to your xmlns:my namespace definition, you have to add the assembly clause, to specify to which assembly the namespace belongs.

Comment: This is not feasible as I have a lot of nested User Controls. I am currently porting a WinForms application to WPF. If UserControls are so buggy, I simply won't use them.

Comment: So, the app works, but there is a squiggly line under that line of code in the designer? Is this really an issue? Annoying, sure. A real problem, no.

Comment: @rabejens It's the XAML designer that's problematic. There's a reason why you can disable the designer entirely `Tools->Options->XAML Designer -> Uncheck Enable XAML Designer`

Comment: @rabejens could you show the xaml for your usercontrol xaml I will try to replicated it.

Comment: A rebuild usually fixes designer-only issues like that for me. But if it's more than just an designer issue, and actually preventing it from compiling, then I'd recommend right-clicking on the file in Solution Explorer and checking the "Build Action" for the UserControl. Sometimes I find when I copy/paste stuff it gets set to the wrong value.

Comment: Unfortunately it is company code so I am not allowed to show any actual code, but for the complex controls, I will put them in a separate assembly.